# How to open or pick multiple images in windows store with PickMultipleFilesAsync() using c#?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to pick **multiple** images (from any folder) and show them in imagebox. I have to use IReadOnlyStream<> and foreach loop but how?
The logic of my code is

`           FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

```
        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        StorageFile file = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleMultipleAsync(); 
        if(file != null)
        {
            textBlock.Text = file.Name;
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(fileStream);
            image1.Source = bmp;
```

}

Comment: You want to show multiple images in a single Image control? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to Use to Pick Multiple files (Media files) and retrieve them in a StorageFile collection at custom/desired index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417263/what-to-use-to-pick-multiple-files-media-files-and-retrieve-them-in-a-storagef)