# Want to Open multiple audio files and play them in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to open multiple audio files in UWP using the `FileOpenPicker` but I am getting an error that I cant Cannot Convert. How can I fix this?
And if this is fixed, will all the audio files play in order or all at the same time?

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
MediaSource media_source;
MediaPlayer media_player;


public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenfileAsync()
{
    var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".ogg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");

    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

    StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        media_source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        media_player = new MediaPlayer();
        media_player.Source = media_source;
        mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(media_player);
        media_player.Play();
    }
}

private async void Select_track_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await OpenfileAsync();
}
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenMultipleAsync()
{
    var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".ogg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

    StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {

        media_source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        media_player = new MediaPlayer();
        media_player.Source = media_source;
        mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(media_player);
        media_player.Play();

    }

}
private async void playlist_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await OpenMultipleAsync();
}
```

I am getting the error at `StorageFile file = await filepicker.PickmultiplefilesAsync();`

Comment: I'm guessing `PickMultipleFilesAsync()` returns more than one `StorageFile`. (i.e. perhaps an array? A list? An IEnumerable etc?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to Use to Pick Multiple files (Media files) and retrieve them in a StorageFile collection at custom/desired index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417263/what-to-use-to-pick-multiple-files-media-files-and-retrieve-them-in-a-storagef)

Comment: I updated my code for you guys,

Comment: @Dizzy You've changed the code so that it only tries to open a single file - are you still having the same issue, as it would seem the context of the question has changed somewhat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync` method has the following signature:

```
IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>> PickMultipleFilesAsync()
```

In contrast to `PickFileAsync` it returns a `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>`, so you will actually get a list of multiple files the user selected. You should update the code like this:

```
var files = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        media_source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        media_player = new MediaPlayer();
        media_player.Source = media_source;
        mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(media_player);
        media_player.Play();
    }
}
```

This solution will play all the sounds at once. For one by one playback you can use @touseefbsb solution :-) .

Comment: Won't creating too many media players create a lag if we have videos playing along with audio?

Answer (score 1):

for playing a list of files its best that you use [MediaPlaybackList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource#play-a-list-of-media-items-with-mediaplaybacklist)

Also you only need to set the **SuggestedStartLocation** once, and when you use **PickMultipleFilesAsync()** you get a List of files returned so you need that iterate through that list to get all files and add them to your **MediaPlaybackList**

> Modify your **OpenMultipleAsync** method like this :

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenMultipleAsync()
{
    var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".ogg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

    _mediaPlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList();

    var files = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file));
        _mediaPlaybackList.Items.Add(mediaPlaybackItem);
    }

    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    _mediaPlayer.Source = _mediaPlaybackList;
    mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(_mediaPlayer);
}
```

More details about **MediaPlaybackItem** can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlaybackItem)

> and to answer 'will these media files play together at the same time or one after the other' : they will play one after the other in a row, that is the purpose if MediaPlaybackList, it supports gapless playback for playlists.